# Graph database referencing cassandra tables

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

I have a scenario where I would like to model my IoT asset in a the graph database of DataStax Enterprise.  This is a perfect fit for my hierarchical data structure.  However, when it comes to my time series data I already have that stored in a separate Cassandra table.  Is there a way to bridge the gap between data in the graph database and data in a standard cassandra table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this current moment, all data needs to reside in DSE Graph tables to be available via Gremlin traversals for OLTP or OLAP use cases.  We have features coming out soon though that will help provide an OLAP scenario.  We'd love to learn more about your use case though to enhance the product for this type of scenario.  If you'd like, please join the DataStax Academy Graph channel and we can discuss this requirement further - https://academy.datastax.com/slack